# System.IO.FileNotFoundException on System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, polly

I have the following code

```
    try
    {
        using (var client = HttpClientBuilder.CreateClient(PingTimeoutMilliseconds, true))
        {
            var response = await Policy
                .Handle<Exception>(ex => ex is HttpRequestException || ex is TaskCanceledException)                        
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
                {
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
                }, (ex, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
                {
                    loggerService.Log(ex);
                    loggerService.Log($"Ping request failed. Waiting {timeSpan} seconds before next retry. Retry attempt {retryCount}");
                })
                .ExecuteAsync(() => client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, uri)));
            IsInternetAvailable = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
    }
```

And some of the clients are complaining about an exception

Uitzonderingsinformatie: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException

bij Showpad.OutlookDesktopAddIn.Infrastructure.Helpers.PingHelper+<IsInternetAvailableAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Showpad.OutlookDesktopAddIn.Infrastructure.Helpers.PingHelper+<IsInternetAvailableAsync>d__5, Showpad.OutlookDesktopAddIn, Version=2.7.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]](<IsInternetAvailableAsync>d__5 ByRef)
```

I might suspect that something might be wrong with Polly library (since there is an IO exception) at line 5 await Policy

```
using Polly;
```

Comment: Polly has no run-time dependencies on loading other modules, and Polly does no I/O itself (can just be used to guard I/O you execute through a policy), so I wouldn't immediately suspect a problem with Polly here.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileNotFoundException` has a property called `FileName`([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filenotfoundexception.filename?view=netcore-3.1)).

Please check that first and for the reasoning please scrutinize the `FusionLog`([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filenotfoundexception.fusionlog?view=netcore-3.1)) as well.